# Two collection views, one won't display cells

Tags: swift

I have two `CollectionViews` in one `ViewController`.
I want to display both on the screen at the same time, but for some reason the second CollectionView won't display any cells.

This is what I have:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mainView.popularCollection.dataSource = self
    mainView.popularCollection.delegate = self
    mainView.popularCollection.register(PopularMovieCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: popularCell)

    mainView.upcomingMoviesCollection.dataSource = self
    mainView.upcomingMoviesCollection.delegate = self
    mainView.upcomingMoviesCollection.register(UpcomingMovieCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: upcomingCell)

    //TODO: change popularMovies to trending movies.
    NetworkingManager.shared.getPopularMovies { (fetchedMovies) in
        self.fetchedPopularMovies = fetchedMovies
    }

    NetworkingManager.shared.getUpComingMovies { (upcomingMovies) in
        self.fetchedUpcomingMovies = upcomingMovies
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {        
    if collectionView == mainView.upcomingMoviesCollection {
        return fetchedUpcomingMovies.count
    }
    return fetchedPopularMovies.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if collectionView == mainView.upcomingMoviesCollection {
        let upComingCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: upcomingCell, for: indexPath) as! UpcomingMovieCell
        let movie = self.fetchedUpcomingMovies[indexPath.row]

        if let poster = movie.poster_path {
            upComingCell.movieImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: baseImgUrl + poster)
        }else {
            upComingCell.movieImage.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
        }
        upComingCell.movieNameLabel.text = movie.title
        upComingCell.movieReleasedate.text = movie.release_date

        return upComingCell
    }


    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: popularCell, for: indexPath) as! PopularMovieCell
    let movie = self.fetchedPopularMovies[indexPath.row]
    var genreString = ""

    if let poster = movie.poster_path {
        cell.movieImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: baseImgUrl + poster)
    }else {
        cell.movieImage.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
    }
    cell.movieNameLabel.text = movie.title
    cell.ratingScoreLabel.text = String(movie.vote_average)

    //A movie may have few genres, so we get every genre code of the specific movie, translating it to a genre name, and adding it to one string.
    for genre in movie.genre_ids {
        if let genre = genresById[genre] {
            genreString = genreString + " " + genre + ", "
            genreString = genreString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        }
    }
    //Removing the last char in the string if it is ","
    if genreString.last == "," {
        genreString.removeLast()
    }
    cell.movieGenre.text = genreString

    return cell
}
```

I saw that this code is the correct answer in few similar questions, but for me it won't work for some reason.

I checked, and I get in fetchedUpcomingMoves.count the number 0, but when I print it I get 20. I do not understand why it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried to add breakpoints to the numberOfItems section and see if the item count is correct? Or add a breakpoint at the cellForItemAt to see if the missing cells are being fetched?

Comment: @ShunzheM Yes, I added that I get 0 in the return, but when I print it before, I get 20.

Comment: `<#respective table view#>.reloadData()` after setting the values (inside network completion block)

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are returning the correct number of cells and the cell for different collection views. One issue I suspect is:

The part where you fetches the data might be on a different thread so maybe try to update the collection views once you have the data?

```
NetworkingManager.shared.getPopularMovies { (fetchedMovies) in
    self.fetchedPopularMovies = fetchedMovies
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        mainView.popularCollection.reloadData()
    }
}

NetworkingManager.shared.getUpComingMovies { (upcomingMovies) in
    self.fetchedUpcomingMovies = upcomingMovies
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        mainView.upcomingCollection.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Follow up if that does not work

Comment: Thanks! Working great now!

Comment: Nice! Glad to know my answer helps ;)